# How can I use Gotos with Cython (using python 3.5)?

Tags: python, cython, goto

As the title say, I want to use gotos in cython. I know you are going to insult me, so let me first say that I hate gotos just as much as anyone. The reason I ask is very specific: I am currently writting a software that translate from an old programming language to python/Cython. There are over a 1000 programms to translate, which is why automation is crucial. 
     It has been a breeze up till now, but the old language uses gotos, and while having gotos in pure python is easy thanks to a few packages, these packages break when I use cython to compile the code. I could of course place the gotos in parts of the python code I do not compile with cython, but the automation would be more complete if I didn't have to care about that.
         Does anyone have a better solution? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in adavance !

Comment: Why not translate it to C and then create a Python interface to the C functions with Cython?

Comment: Mmh I didn't think of that. You mean translating the entire programm in C? I don't want to do it this way because the people who will be using this software don't really have an IT background so I am trying to keep it as simple as possible, and thus full python (with some type definitions for performance). Another issue is that the programms don't use functions, they only use gotos, loops and conditions, so that makes the task a bit harder. Thanks anyway, certainly not a bad idea!

Comment: Translate the gotos to functions and call them like any other function.